# merging dataframes with different and unknown fields

Tags: python, pandas

As a toy example I have the following pandas dataframes from scraping a website

```
[       num :                  2
0       ma1 :                  1
1       ma2 :                0.2
2       ma3 :                  5
3       ma4 :                1.8]

[       num :                  2
0       ma1 :                  1
1       ma2 :                0.2
2       ma3 :                  5
3       ma4 :                1.8
4       ma5 :                  7]
```

I want to merge them together into a database without prior knowledge of all the field names. To do this I believe I need to convert them into something that looks similar to below to enable me to append them.

```
[       num :    ma1:    ma2:    ma3:   ma4:
0           2       1     0.2      5     1.8]   

[       num :    ma1:    ma2:    ma3:   ma4:    ma5:
0           2       1     0.2      5     1.8       7]
```

Is this a sensible approach and how might I be able to implement it?

Comment: How about a join operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need list comprehesnion with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
dfs = [x.set_index(x.columns[0]).T for x in dfs]
```

If need join them together add [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([x.set_index(x.columns[0]) for x in dfs], axis=1).T
```

Comment: this is nice one !